# Angular HTTP call does not triggers? Nothing happens

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular of course :)
I have a list and I use [(ngModel)] to display an element of this list. Then I want to update this selected element and persist the changes with a button.
this is my code :

html component

```
<div *ngIf="selectedAction">
  <label>Titre :
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedAction.title" />
  </label><br />
  <label>Détails :
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedAction.details" />
  </label><br />
  <label>Date limite :
      <input [ngModel]="selectedAction.date_limite | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="selectedAction.date_limite=$event" />
  </label><br />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
    (click)="save();"
    style="float: none;">Modifier</button>
  <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary"
    (click)="clear()"
    style="float: none;">Cacher</button>
</div>
<!-- Affichage de la liste des actions -->
<h2>Ma liste d'action</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <!-- Lors du click sur l'élément de la liste, la méthode onSelect() s'exécute -->
    <li *ngFor="let action of actions" (click)="onSelect(action)" class="list-group-item" style="padding: 0.25rem 1.25rem;">
      <span>{{ action.title | uppercase }}</span>
      <span>: {{ action.details }}</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="delete action"
          (click)="delete(action)">Archiver</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

ts component with the save() action for the 'Modifier' button

```
save(): void {
    this.actionService.updateAction(this.selectedAction);
  }
```

Then the service component

```
updateAction (action: Action): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.actionsUrl, action, httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateAction'))
    );
  }
```

Actually, when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Thx for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make a call to HTTP in Angular (which is based on RxJS Observable), you should **subscribe** it. You forgot to subscribe the updateAction() method which returns an Observable. Only when you **subscribe** to an **Observable**, the HTTP call will happen.

```
save(): void {
    this.actionService.updateAction(this.selectedAction).subscribe();
 }
```

You need to update the list in the subscribe method. Which will in return re render in html to produce the output.